# How can I open Google Maps URL Scheme on iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps

AS [google map SDK doc description](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/urlscheme?utm_source=welovemapsdevelopers&utm_campaign=GM-for-iOS-sdk-1-7), we can use the code below to call native google maps to finish directions. But how can I test these code on my Xcode? it always return "can't use comgooglemaps://"?

```
if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:
 [NSURL URLWithString:@"comgooglemaps://"]]) {
 [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:
 [NSURL URLWithString:@"comgooglemaps://?center=40.765819,-73.975866&zoom=14&views=traffic"]];
 } else {NSLog(@"Can't use comgooglemaps://");
}
```

Comment: When you say "on my Xcode" do you mean the iOS simulator?  If so, you cannot install the google maps app on the simulator, so you cannot test.  You will need to use a real device.

Comment: Thanks! Your answer is exactly what I want to get

Answer (score 4):

If it is iOS 9 you might want to try this: under info
custom iOS taget properties, LSApplicationQueriesSchemes. add comgooglemaps

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[Apple Dev Notes](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIApplication/canOpenURL%3a) say "*NO if no app is available that will accept the URL; otherwise, returns YES*."

Make sure you have Google Maps installed, not the default Apple maps App.

Answer (score 0):

Opening that URL requires the Google Maps app to be installed.  You can't install apps from the app store on the simulator (they aren't compiled for x86 as a start), so you will need to test on an actual device